# Google Analytics gtag.js Iframe Cross-domain Clientid issue

Tags: iframe, google-analytics

Our goal here is to keep Google Analytics conversion goal tracking data when we load an iframe from another domain name that we own.

We have a domain rentalbookingsoftware.com that on the free trial page: https://rentalbookingsoftware.com/free-trial-signup/ loads an iframe for our free trial installer from sidev2.info like this:

`<iframe width="80%" height="500" src="https://sidev2.info/freetrialform.php"></iframe>`

We are trying to keep the gtag.js clientid the same but a new session is started on the sidev2.info gtag tracking which causes the correct referrer information to be lost as you can see from the gtag recording: https://www.screencast.com/t/l5wsqUF6oAg . Both sites are using this tracking code as suggested from:  https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gtagjs/cross-domain and I have added sidev2.info to the referrer exclusion list: https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2795830

```
<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-45446232-1"></script>
<script>
  window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
  function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
  gtag('js', new Date());
  gtag('config', 'UA-45446232-1', {
  'linker': {
    'domains': ['rentalbookingsoftware.com', 'sidev2.info']
    }
  });
</script>
```

How can we keep the clientid using gtags? I found this: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/cross-domain but it is for analytics.js tracking, should we switch to that tracking method?